# How to get the month start date from input_date

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am developing an API where the user enters an input date in this format: 2019-07-29 which will be converted to date time to get '2019-07-29'. This will be used in queries against the database.

```
input_date = str(input_date)
input_date_formatted = "'" + datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "'"
```

I am trying to get the start of the month date for whichever input_date in this fashion: `XXXX-XX-01`. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not change `strftime` to parse it as you desire: `strftime('%Y-%m-01')`?

Comment: I'll try it ! thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: `datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` is same as `input_date` What are you doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using it as a datetime and not a string later you can do this as follows (assuming `input_date` is a string):

```
date = datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
first_day_of_month = date.replace(day=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you might need the actual input and the start of the month date.
By that logic the following code might just work out for you.

```
from datetime import datetime
input_date = '2019-07-29'
input_date = str(input_date)
input_date_formatted = "'" + datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "'"
input_date_formatted = input_date_formatted[:9]+"01'"
print(input_date_formatted)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
input_date = '2019-07-29'
input_date_object = datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
first_date_object = input_date_object.date().replace(day=1)
print (first_date_object) # <class 'datetime.date'>
print (first_date_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) # <class 'str'>
```

output:

```
2019-07-01
2019-07-01
```

NOTE:

> Use `datetime.date` to get just date without hours:minutes:seconds
>
> The function `replace()` is to replace specific or all the attributes
>   of a datetime object.
>
> Date attributes of a datetime object that can be replaced by the
>   replace() function:
>
> - year
> - month
> - day